# Как использовать JColorChooser?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Как добавлять `JColorChooser`, я разобрался, а как его именно использовать, чтобы, к примеру, я выбрал цвет, и поменялся фон?

Answer (score 0):

```java
jButton.addActionListener((a) -> jPanel.setBackground(JColorChooser.showDialog(null,"ColorChooser", Color.RED)));
```